# The example code of composition vs aggregation?

Tags: oop, composition

I'm new to OOP design there are a lot article about composition vs aggregation, but I can't find the real code example, so I write a simple one:

```
class Car
    attr_reader :model, :valve
    attr_writer :passenger
    def initialize(model, valve)
        @model = model
        @engine = Engine.new(valve) 
    end
    def run 
        puts "wowowowo"
    end
end

class Engine 
    def initialize(valve)
        @valve = valve
    end
end

class Passenger
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end

p = Passenger.new("Foo")
car = Car.new("9-3 convertible", 4)
car.passenger(p)
```

Here's the reasons for the decisions:

1. For this case, the engine instance will be unusable, when its **owner** car instance no longer existed. So the engine follow the car life cycle.
2. engine is part of the car, so Car **own** the engine.
3. Passenger instance still useable when the car instance no longer existed, so passenger has it's own life cycle,

Please point out if I have something wrong about this, and does my code is good design?

---

update: To clarify, I think Car -> Engine is composition, Car -> Passenger is Aggregation

Comment: You didn't state which example you thought was composition, and which was aggregation.  [This article](http://design-antony.blogspot.com/2007/07/aggregation-vs-composition.html) has a very clear explanation of both.

Comment: I've updated the question, thanks for point out this issue

Answer (score 0):

**Composition**

When there is a composition between two entities, the composed object **cannot** exist without the other entity.
A composition is a strong Association whereas Aggregation is a weak Association.

***Tree*** - ***Leaf*** is ***composition***. A leaf is a ***part of*** Tree. The leaf can not exist without the tree.

**Aggregation**

When there is a composition between two entities, the composed object **can** exist without the other entity.

***Car*** - ***Engine*** is ***aggregation***. Because if the car stops working, and we delete it from our database, the engine will not be deleted because it may still be functional. We can use this engine inside another car.